# Fake coin detection and relationship between coins and comparisons

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, puzzle

I am reading about the problem of detecting a fake coin among a collection of $m$ coins optimally.
The first task is to define what we mean by optimally.
It starts with $m$ coins as a given and the following reasoning:

> If we compare 2 coins by their weights we have 3 possible outcomes of
> such a comparison which are tip to the left, tip to the right and even
> balance.   So with $n$ comparisons we have $3^n$ different outcomes at
> most

So far so good. Then

> Suppose we have $m$ coins and at most 1 is fake. Then there are $1 + 2m$
> possible possibilities which are 1 (all genuine) + $m$ (one of the m
> coins is fake/lighter) + $m$ (one of the m coins is fake/heavier)

(a) At this point I am not really sure why it is $2m$ and not $\frac 2 m$ since it is $\frac 1 m$ that is fake (heavier/lighter).

Then it says:

> with $n$ comparisons, the number of coins among which a fake can be
> detected is at most $m$ where $1 + 2m = 3^n$.   More precisely if the
> number of m coins is greater than $\frac {(3^n - 1)} 2$ then it is not possible
> to guarantee we can find the fake coin with n comparisons

So optimally here means with $n$ comparisons.

(b) At this point though I don't really understand how the $n$ (as number of comparisons) showed up and determined/defined $m$ when all we had as given when we started is that we have $m$ coins.

Could someone please help me with (a) and (b)

Comment: (a) We are talking about the number of possible outcomes here, and 1/m is not even a number. How would you interpret having a $1\over10$ of an outcome?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: I am not sure what is the difference. It is `1/m` that is fake. There are `m` possible coins to be fake. So the latter is a number only? What is `1/m` defined as then?

Comment: An outcome is a statement like _"The first coin is fake and heavier"_, or _"The second coin is fake and lighter"_, or _"All coins are genuine"_. Can you have a fraction of that? No, you can't.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: It says `possible possibilities` and not possible outcomes though. May be I am misreading it?

Comment: It is intended to be understood "possible outcomes", just phrased poorly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: @saulspatz:Thank you for that! I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a, let there be $m=5$ coins.  We can call them $A,B,C,D,E$.  It is asserted that there are $2 \cdot 5+1=11$ possibilities.  Either one of the coins is heavy ($5$ possibilities because it can be any coin), all the coins are correct, or one of the coins is light (again $5$ possibilities.)

For b, let us continue with $m=5$.  Each weighing has $3$ possible results.  If we weigh twice, there are $3 \cdot 3=9$ possible results.  As we can only distinguish $9$ possibilities with two weighings, it must take at least $3$ weighings to find a possible fake coin among $5$.  You determine $n$ by finding the smallest $n$ so that $3^n \ge 2m+1$ so you can distinguish enough possibilities.  This does not prove that the coin can be found in $n$ tries, it only proves that it cannot be found with certainty in $n-1$.  To prove that $n$ will work, one needs to lay out a strategy of weighings.

$m=5, n=3$ should be easy because $3^3=27$ is so much more than $11$.  We first weigh $AB$ vs $CD$.  If they balance $ABCD$ are all good and we weigh $E$ against any other coin and have the result.  If $AB$ are heavier than $CD$ we can have either of $AB$ heavy or $CD$ light.  We can then weigh $AC$ against $BD$.  If $AC$ is heavy either $A$ is heavy or $D$ is light.  We weigh $A$ against $B$ and have the answer.  The other results are similar.  We have shown that $3$ weighings suffice for $m=5$ coins.

Comment: `As we can only distinguish 9 possibilities with two weighings, it must take at least 3 weighings to find a possible fake coin among 5` I dont understand this part. Could you please elaborate a bit? Are you talking about weighing $A$ and $B$ and then $B$ and $C$? So 9 possibilities?

Comment: Results are left heavier, balance, or right heavier.  The point there is that whatever you weigh, in two tries you can only get $9$ different results.  As there are $11$ possibilities, there must be at least two pairs or one triplet that share a result by the pigeonhole principle.  To have an answer to the problem, each possibility must have a unique set of results so you can tell it from the others.

Comment: So basically the number of possible results by the number of weightings have to be more than the number of coins  based on this equation: $1+2=3$. Is that correct?

Comment: Because the original text states that it should not be greater. So should it be also $ 1+2<=3.$ ?

Comment: No.  We need $3^n \ge 1+2m$ as I wrote before.  The number of possible results from $n$ weighings is $3^n$ because you get a factor $3$ from each one.

Comment: `If  is heavy either  is heavy or  is light. We weigh  against  and have the answer.` If we weigh $A$ against $D$ in your example we would see that one is heavier/lighter than the other but it seems to me we would still wouldn't know which one is fake. It could be either $A$ or $D$ again since we are not comparing with a genuine coin. Seems the same issue if we have just 1 coin to begin with. We don't have a genuine coin to compare it with

Comment: Yes, the third weighing should be $A$ vs $B$ because $B$ is known to be good.  You are right that if you have only one coin, or even two, you can't answer.  If you have two, you can weigh them against each other.  If they balance they are both good but if they do not you can't tell which is good.  The classic problem is $12$ coins in $3$ weighings where you know one coin is bad but not whether it is heavy or light.  You can look up the $12$ coin problem for the answer.  You can also do $13$ if you are given a separate known good coin.

Comment: `you can only get 9 different results. As there are 11 possibilities, there must be at least two pairs or one triplet that share a result by the pigeonhole principle`. Why 2 pairs or 1 triplet and not just 2 (i.e 11 - 9) results? What do we mean by 2 pairs or 1 triplet here?

Comment: If you put 11 things into 9 holes, you either have two holes with two each or one hole with three.  You could have more if one or more holes are empty.

Comment: The approach to consider a set for the possibilities observed by $n$ weightings with cardinality $3^n$ and a set for the possibilities we can observe for $m$ coins with cardinality $1 + 2m$ and requiring that the former has higher cardinality than the latter, does it have a name as a method? (assuming that the way I tried to phrase it is meaningful)

Comment: I would say it is an application of the pigeonhole principle.  When $3^n \lt 1+2m$ you are guaranteed to have at least two possibilities sharing a set of results.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If you have the time for it, a question on the same topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980491/is-there-some-convention-on-treatment-of-sets-of-objects-when-defining-an-induct