# Conventions for defining inductive base case

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, induction, problem-solving, puzzle

I was reading a problem that stated:

> There are a certain number of objects all of which have the same
> weight except for one which has a different weight. In all other
> aspects the objects are identical. Determine the unique one that has
> the different weight using a pair of scales optimally. Show by induction on $n$ that at most $2*n$ comparisons are needed to identify the object when the total number of objects is $3^n$

My original thought was that the base case has to be $n = 1$ where we have a total of $3^1$ objects which we can figure out the one we are searching for with 2 comparisons.
But the solution uses as base case $n = 0$ considering in that case that the $3^0 = 1$ object is the one we are searching for. I originally rejected $n = 0 $ as base case because with $1$ object we can't do any comparison so we can't know if it is the one we search for or not.

So my question is: how do we determine in such cases how do we treat the base case? Could we also not have considered that for $n = 0$ the $1$ coin can not be the one we are searching for? Or even that as I originally thought that it is not meaningful to use $n = 0$ as base case?

Is there something in the problems we need to be cautious of, or some convention that exists that helps define the base case?
In this particular problem, it makes me think that there is some subtle implication that the specific unique object under search **must** be part of the set even if all the rest are missing which I did not pick up.
Is that so? Is there some convention for inductive approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use whatever works for your base case, then carefully state what you have proved.  If you use $n=1$ as your base case, you have not proved the $n=0$ case.  You would have to state your result as "For all numbers of objects $n \ge 1$, it takes at most $2n$ comparisons ..."

If I were doing the proof, I would probably start with $n=1$.  Having done it, I would think about $n=0$ for completeness and prove the $n=0$ case separately.  I would wind up proving $n=0$ and $n=1$ directly, then using induction for everything above $1$.  The case of $n=0$ is often different and it can be easier to make the induction work starting from $n=1$.

The base case can be higher yet.  One we see here is to prove $n! \gt n^2$ for $n \ge 4$.  We can note that the statement is not true for $n=3$ as $3!=6 \not \gt 3^2=9$.  You use $4$ as the base case and the induction goes through nicely.

Comment: What about the statement that if there is only $1$ object in the set it is considered as the one we are searching for? Couldn't we equally claim that it is *not* the one we are looking for? The confusing part to me here is where the confidence for the claim comes from.

Comment: From that point of view you could refuse to do the $n=0,1,2$ cases as the answer is not defined.  You could then use $n=3$ for your base case and show that you can succeed with $2$ comparisons.

Comment: So is it a matter of how we define it and both approaches (base case is $n = 0$ or base case $n > 2$) are considered correct as long as they explicitly state the logic? I am trying to think of the problem also in terms of a computer program where we would have a collection with 1 element. Is there any kind of hint or math convention that would bias returning as found the element having as input a collection with 1 item (same as the problem solution is treating it)?

Comment: Yes.  It is more an English question whether you accept the cases $0$ through $2$.

Comment: By an "English question" is how one understand the problem statement? In this specific problem statement in the post, does the way that it is phrased gives hint about one approach or another for the base case?

Comment: I just want to make sure that I am not missing something in the way to read the problem(s)

Comment: Yes, an English question refers to one where the important thing is how you interpret the problem statement.  You raised the possibility that the question does not make sense for less than $3$ coins and on rereading the question I agree.  Often problems are not clear about edge cases like this.  In this case I suspect the problem writer was only thinking about large enough $n$, which turns out to be $3$ or more, and did not specify what happens for the smallest $n$.

Comment: I have another question about induction if by any chance you have some spare time to check. Any help is highly appreciated https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987470/wrong-naive-inductive-hypothesis-and-tower-of-hanoi-as-an-example