# Wrong/naive inductive hypothesis and tower of hanoi as an example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation, puzzle

I am reading about how a wrong formulation of the tower of Hanoi and the inductive hypothesis can lead to a dead-end.
The example I am reading states the following:

> The task is to move N discs from a *specific* pole to another
> *specific* pole. Assume there are poles $A$, $B$ and $C$.   The **base case** is that when the number of discs is 0 then no steps are needed
> to complete the tasks.      For the **inductive step** assume that we
> can move $n$ discs from pole $A$ to pole $B$ and we are required to
> show how to move $n + 1$ discs from $A$ to $B$

Then it highlights that this definition is a dead-end since the only 2 ways to use the induction hypothesis as set don't lead anywhere.
Specifically the options are:

> 1. Move the top $n$ discs from pole $A$ to $B$. After this point all possibilities of using the induction hypothesis have been exhausted
>    since $n$ discs are on pole $B$ and we do not have hypothesis about
>    moving discs from that pole.
> 2. Move the smallest disc from pole $A$ to $C$. Then move the remaining $n$ discs from $A$ to $B$. Once again we have exhausted all
>    possibilities of using the induction hypothesis, because $n$ discs are
>    now on pole $B$, and we have no hypothesis about moving discs from
>    this pole.

The reasoning for $1$ is clear to me. If we move the top $n$ discs i.e. the $n$ smaller discs to pole $B$ then at some point we would have to move them again since we would need to place the $nth + 1$ remaining largest disc bellow them. And there is no inductive hypothesis for that so I think I get it.

I need help with the second part. How I understand it is we move the smallest disc to pole $C$. Then we use the inductive hypothesis to move the remaining $n$ larger discs from pole $A$ to $B$. (At this part I am not sure how this could happen if pole $C$ is occupied by the smallest disc but I guess it is part of the logic of using induction in proof.)
Then at that state it seems to me that the only thing pending would be to move the smallest disc from $C$ to $B$ and finish the task.
Why does it state that we would need to move the $n$ discs from pole $B$ and that is not possible since we don't have an induction hypothesis?
Am I misunderstanding something about statements on induction here?

Comment: You should move the $n$ smallest disks from $A$ to $C$, move the largest disk from $A$ to $B$, then move the $n$ smallest disks from $C$ to $B$ as the problem specifies moving from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to where you are reading this?

Comment: @RossMillikan: The induction hypothesis though is about moving $n$ smallest disk from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @Christoph: The book Algorithmic Problem Solving (Backhouse) page 149

Comment: @RossMillikan: I am not defining the induction. The example is about a wrong approach to induction hypothesis and I am trying to understand the second part of the example

Comment: @Jim You need to rephrase the induction hypothesis as *It is possible to move $n$ disks from pole $X$ to pole $Y$ assuming there exists an extra available pole $Z$.* Then assign the roles of $X,Y,Z$ among $A,B;C$ as needed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that is not how it is stated where I read it from though. That is not my definition. I am just studying the example

Answer (score 2):

You are right to be concerned about the second part.

Your statement of the only thing pending is correct. However, the second part is nonsense since the only sensible inductive hypothesis concerns 'moving n discs from pole A to pole B, assuming that 3 poles are available'.

**An added observation**

Looking at your queries in the various comments I feel it might be useful to point out that proof by induction and proof by minimal counterexample are logically equivalent but that some of the things you are questioning seem so much clearer w.r.t. the minimal counterexample method.

If you are trying to prove a result then

(1) Assume it is false.

(2) Consider a counterexample which in some well-defined sense is minimal.

(3) Then try to prove the result **by whatever means you wish** but where, whenever you need to, you can assume the result for anything 'smaller'.

As an example of the benefits of this way of thinking you can see from this that distinctions such as 'strong' and 'weak' induction are just a distracting irrelevance.

Comment: ah so the emphasis is that the movement in the hypothesis depends on 2 other poles available?

Comment: I was wondering if the meaning is that the inductive hypothesis must be possible to be applied to all smaller instances of the problem for the whole induction proof to hold? The only thing I can think of is that once the smaller disc has been moved to pole $C$ and the smaller $n$ discs have been moved to pole $B$ then we should be able to apply the induction hypothesis to $n-1$ discs which would imply moving them out of pole $B$ hence the problem with the hypothesis. But I dont know how to properly formulate this thought if it makes sense

Comment: I find the entire 'dead end' idea somewhat unhelpful. When you are performing an induction proof you aren' t limited to **only** using the induction hypothesis. You are perfectly correct in saying "I can now move the smallest disc ... ".

Comment: Similarly at the end of case 1  it is valid to then say "by symmetry ..." and then apply the hypothesis to whichever poles we wish (with up to n discs). My advice, since you clearly understand induction, is to consign the 'wrong  formulation' to the waste bin.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: the author’s explanation of the problem with the second part is rubbish. He should instead have pointed to the problems that you saw:

- The induction hypothesis is incomplete, since it pretty clearly must include a requirement that pole $C$ be available for the disks being transferred from $A$ to $B$.
- If the transfer of the bottom $n$ disks from $A$ to $B$ actually **were** possible, we clearly could complete the job of transferring the whole stack by moving the smallest disk from $C$ to $B$.

The problem here isn’t really that the induction hypothesis leads to a dead end: it’s that it is too strong and allows a fallacious argument if this problem isn’t noticed in time.

Comment: `it’s that it is too strong` that is very interesting because the same author mentions in the next section that we need a **stronger** inductive hypothesis which states should be: `move n smallest disks from one pole to either of the other two`

Comment: @Jim: It is actually both: it is too strong in that it allows us to make an unjustified inference, and it is too weak in that it fails to include a hypothesis that is in fact needed to prove the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the second leads to a dead end is because having moved the smallest disk to $C$ you can't move the bottom $n$ disks to $B$ because you can't use $C$ to transfer them.  If you could, this would work fine.  The bottom $n$ disks are on $B$ and you just move the top disk onto them and are done.

Comment: The inductive assumption is: `We can move $n disks from $A$ to $B`. First we move the smallest disk from $A$ to $C$. Then if we use the inductive assumption the rest $n$ (larger) disks can be moved from $A$ to $B$ by induction. So if I combine what you are saying, it means that the smaller instances of the problem i.e. for smaller $k<n$ we can't reuse the inductive assumption because we can't move the disks out of $B$. Do I make sense here? If yes how can this be formally described?

Comment: The inductive assumption should be We can move $n$ disks from $A$ to $B$ if $C$ is available to all the disks.  If you move the small disk to $C$ you can move $1$ disk from $A$ to $B$, but not $2$.  This is why the $n$ disks in the induction are the small ones, not the large ones.

Comment: The specific case, tries to show a bad formulation of the inductive assumption and to do that, it follows the route of trying to apply the assumption repeatedly. In the assumption there is no explicit mention of using $C$ for the transfer although I agree with you that it is required. Could it be that it is implicit?

Comment: `This is why the  disks in the induction are the small ones, not the large ones.` I am not sure where this is from. There is not mention of $n$ small ones

Comment: Not mentioning the need of $C$ hides the fact that it is needed.  If you don't realize that it is needed, the induction goes through when it should not.

Comment: I understand that but I did not define the induction. The example I am reading mentioned in the post did it the way described. Are you saying that the point of the example is that by not mentioning $C$ the induction is broken?

Comment: Yes.  The proper way to phrase it would be that you can move a pile of $n$ disks from any pole to any other pole with a spare pole available.  That avoids the problem of whether you are moving from $A$ to $B$ or $A$ to $C$.  When you move the smallest disk first you don't have a spare pole available, so the induction fails.  I suspect the point of the example is to show how unstated assumptions can make an induction fail.

Comment: An induction hypothesis when stated for $n$ is supposed to hold for all smaller sub-instances of the problem recursively, isn't that right? 
Doesn't that mean that when we state an induction hypothesis for $n$ it holds first for $n - 1$ or all $n - x$ where $0 <= x <= n$, since it is the smaller instance of $n - 1$ or generally $n - x$ that supports the hypothesis for $n$?
In that case then wouldn't that mean that the smaller sub-instances of $n$ need to move the disks out of pole $B$ at some point during the process? Does this formulation make sense excluding $C$?

Comment: Would that interpretation of the text make sense at all?

Comment: That is the only way I can think of that the "not possible" to reuse the inductive hypothesis makes sense

Comment: That is a difference between weak and strong induction.  In weak induction you just use the hypothesis that something works for $n$ to prove it works for $n+1$.  In strong induction you use the hypothesis that it works for all numbers up to $n$ to prove it works for $n+1$.  Weak induction is more common and works here but only if you state the assumption correctly.  We have to view the top disks as the $n$ stated in the assumption, not the bottom ones because we can move the bottom disk does not get in the way of moving the top ones.  We have to say we can use any pole.

Comment: I did not realize that distinction between strong and weak induction, thank you for pointing that out! I always implicitly thought that the numbers before $n$ are also assumed to hold the assumption so that the induction can work like the domino fall that they usually compare it with.